# Byte [] used as a BufferInputStream ok but

Tags: java, io, nio

Ok I know a buffer is actually an array of byte, however I have never seen the following declaration (taken from [here](http://javakenai-dev.cognisync.net/blog/cajo/archive/2010/10/16/adding-google-maps-your-java-application))

```
URLConnection con = new URL("http://maps...").openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
byte bytes[] = new byte[con.getContentLength()];
is.read(bytes);
```

Is it the right way to avoid using a BufferInputStream object? Here we have an unbuffered stream reading from a byte []? should not be the other way around? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not reading from a byte[], it's reading into a byte[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not the right way. Method `read()` reads up to N bytes where N is the length of your array. It can read less bytes (even 0) if no more byte are available. Number of bytes that have been read is returned by method `read()`. When end of stream is reached the method returns `-1`.

Therefore the right way is to read bytes in loop:

```
byte[] buf = new buf[MAX];
int n = 0;
while ((n = stream.read(buf)) >= 0) {
    // deal with n first bytes from buf
}
```

Comment: Why not using a BufferedInputStream at all?

Answer (score 0):

or use Apache commons-io

InputStream is;
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);